# @apollo/client useLazyQuery .then() triggers even when there's an error (React/graphene-django)

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql, apollo-client, graphene-django

I have a graphene-django backend with a `me` query that returns an exception: `You do not have permission to perform this action` if the user is not logged in.

From React I'm calling the query like this:

```js
const [getMe] = useLazyQuery(ME_QUERY); // query not important

React.useEffect(() => {
  getMe()
    .then((meRes) => {
      console.log('Hit the .then()');
      if (meRes.data && meRes.data.me) {
        setUser(meRes.data.me);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Hit the .catch()');
    });
}, [])
```

The response I get from the backend:

```json
{"errors":[{"message":"You do not have permission to perform this action","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["me"]}],"data":{"me":null}}
```

I would expect that @apollo/client would recognize this as an error and my console would output `Hit the .catch()`, but for some reason it's not hitting the catch at all and only outputs `Hit the .then()`.

Why would that response resolve instead of reject in @apollo/client?  I only have this issue with queries, not with mutations which work as expected.  For instance if I call this mutation:

```js
const [createUser, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION);

createUser({
  variables: {
    email,
    password1,
    password2,
  },
}).then(() => {
  console.log('this should not be hit');
});
```

And I receive this response:

```json
{"errors":[{"message":"['This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.', 'This password is too common.']","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["createUser"]}],"data":{"createUser":null}}
```

@apollo/client will correctly recognize that as an error and `this should not be hit` is not seen in the console, even though both the query and mutation return a 200 status code.

Any help understanding why useLazyQuery incorrectly hits .then() but useMutation correctly hits .catch() would be greatly appreciated.  I can provide more explanation on either the Django or React side if needed.

Comment: According to their doc, "The `useLazyQuery` function returns a promise that fulfills with a query result when the query succeeds _or fails_"  (emphasis is mine). This implies that the promise does not reject on query failure. You could use the second object in the tuple returned by `useLazyQuery` to get the error information.

Comment: Oh okay... seems odd to me that that's the case but they must have their reasons.  Unfortunately in my case I need to call `setUser` when the query is successful rather than declaratively display the response with the data/error objects from the tuple.  I guess in this case my `.then()` should manually check for `errors` in the response and decide from there how to handle it.